# Can we embed every finite group in some special orthogonal group or special linear group of some order , over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

For every finite group $G$  , does there exist $n \in \mathbb Z^+$ such that $G$ can be embedded in $SO_n(\mathbb R)$ ? Can every finite group be embedded in $SL_n(\mathbb R)$ for some $n$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. $G$ acts on itself by left multiplication, which gives us an embedding as group of permutation matrices into $GL_{|G|}(\mathbb R)$. Clearly, permutation matrices are orthogonal and have determinant $\pm1$. By adding another dimension that "eats" the sign, we obtain an embedding $G\to GL_{|G|+1}(\mathbb R)$ where the image is in fact in $SL_{|G|+1}$ and $SO_{|G|+1}$.

Comment: I thought of permutation matrices but I wasn't sure what to do about the sign though. Should it be obvious how to use such a "hungry" extra dimension?